# Shorter path to generic constraints

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

I were doing some generic filtering for fun, and then came to some sort of "and" filter, where constraints became a hell to make the generic code work. These are my initial generic interfaces:

```
interface ISpecification<in T>
{
    bool IsSatisfied(T obj);
}

class ColoredSpecification : ISpecification<IColored>
{
    readonly Color color;

    public ColoredSpecification(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfied(IColored iColored)
    {
        return iColored.Color == color;
    }
}

interface IFilter<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> items, ISpecification<T> specification);
}

class ProductFilter : IFilter<Product>
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Filter(IEnumerable<Product> items, ISpecification<Product> specification)
    {
        return items.Where(p => specification.IsSatisfied(p));
    }
}

class GenericFilter<T> : IFilter<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> items, ISpecification<T> specification)
    {
        return items.Where(p => specification.IsSatisfied(p));
    }

    // It is used like this
    static IEnumerable<Product> A()
    {
        var colorSpec = new ColoredSpecification(Color.Black);
        var products = new[]
        {
            new Product { Color = Color.White },
            new Product { Color = Color.Black },
            new Product { Color = Color.Beige }
        };

        return new GenericFilter<Product>().Filter(products, colorSpec);
    }
}
```

Then, there be dragons

```
class AndSpecification<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> : ISpecification<T1>
    where T1 : T2, T3
    where T4 : ISpecification<T2>
    where T5 : ISpecification<T3>
{
    readonly T4 u;
    readonly T5 v;

    public AndSpecification(T4 u, T5 v)
    {
        this.u = u;
        this.v = v;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfied(T1 obj)
    {
        return u.IsSatisfied(obj) && v.IsSatisfied(obj);
    }
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
var colorSpec = new ColoredSpecification(Color.Black);
var sizeSpec = new SizedSpecification(5);
var andSpec = new AndSpecification<Product, IColored, ISized, ColoredSpecification, SizedSpecification>(colorSpec, sizeSpec);

var products = new[]
{
    new Product { Color = Color.White },
    new Product { Color = Color.Black },
    new Product { Color = Color.Beige }
};

return new GenericFilter<Product>().Filter(products, andSpec);
```

Is there a reasonable way to make this work? I mean, like 3 generics arguments would be "reasonable", or just 1, but it doesn't looks possible

Comment: Could you remove `where T1 : T2, T3` and then just use `ISpecification<T1>` for the other constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some generic filtering for fun

The non-[fun](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Losing) answer is just to call `.Where()` multiple times.

Your `IFilter` interface and its implementations don't know the implementation type of the `ISpecification` argument. Your `AndSpecification` type shouldn't need to know either.

```cs
class AndSpecification<T1,T2,T3> : ISpecification<T1> where T1:T2,T3 {
    AndSpecification(ISpecification<T2> u, ISpecification<T3> v){ ... }
    bool IsSatisfied(T1 obj) => u.IsSatisfied(obj) && v.IsSatisfied(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I find out the constructor still very verbose, so, i decided to just:
static IEnumerable<T1> AndFilter<T1, T2, T3>(IEnumerable<T1> items, ISpecification<T2> u, ISpecification<T3> v) where T1 : T2, T3
        {
            return items.Where(obj => u.IsSatisfied(obj) && v.IsSatisfied(obj));
        }